# Angular serve error encounted when the ng --open serve command types on VS

Tags: angular8

When I create angular project on desktop/angular8/firstapp and type the following serve command in visual studio code

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\angular8\firstapp> ng --open serve
```

I get the following error

```
ng : File C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng --open serve
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

What is the reason for this, how can I get rid of this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer

because powershell doesn't support for the angular commands. Then you have to do is,

Remove `ng.ps1` from the directory `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\` then try clearing the npm cache at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\`

Comment: I can not find AppData Flder